# Solution Check: counting how many row-reduced echelon matrices exist in $M_{2\times 3}(\mathbb{Z}_5)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$\mathbb{Z}_5$ is the prime field of order 5. Actually it is $\mathbb{Z}_5 = \{0,1,2,3,4\}$ which its addition and multiplication are defined in hang of $5$ (I think this sentence is not very beautiful, I will appreciate if you say how it is said correctly between mathematicians). For example $2\times 4 = 3$. Alternatively, we can say $\mathbb{Z}_5 = \{[0],[1],[2],[3],[4]\}$ which its elements are equivalent classes.

$M_{n\times m}(F)$ is the set of all $n\times m$ matrices that thier entries are from the field $F$. Hence, $M_{2\times3}(\mathbb{Z}_5)$ is the set of all $2\times3$ matrices which their entries are from the field $\mathbb{Z}_5$.

Now I want to see how many row-reduced echelon matrices are there in $M_{2\times3}(\mathbb{Z}_5)$. My approach:

- One case is zero matrix.
- Matrices with one zero-row:

$\begin{bmatrix}
1 && \text{(5 cases)} && \text{(5 cases)}\\
0 && 0 && 0
\end{bmatrix}$,
$\begin{bmatrix}
0 && 1 && \text{(5 cases)}\\
0 && 0 && 0
\end{bmatrix}$,
$\begin{bmatrix}
0 && 0 && 1\\
0 && 0 && 0
\end{bmatrix}$

- Matrices with no zero-row:

$\begin{bmatrix}
1 && 0 && \text{(5 cases)}\\
0 && 1 && \text{(5 cases)}
\end{bmatrix}$,
$\begin{bmatrix}
1 && \text{(5 cases)} && 0\\
0 && 0 && 1
\end{bmatrix}$,
$\begin{bmatrix}
0 && 1 && 0\\
0 && 0 && 1
\end{bmatrix}$

So there will be $1+(5\times5)+5+1+(5\times5)+5+1=63$ matrices that satisfy in problem conditions. Am I right? Or there are any missing matrices?

Comment: From what I see, there are no left over matrices